# Forward fill an indexed dataframe, but only forward fill per value in index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, ffill

| Year | Month | score1 | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Jan | 98 | NaN | 100 |
|  | feb | NaN | 39 | NaN |
| 2021 | sept | 100 | 50 | NaN |
|  | nov | 100 | NaN | 76 |
|  | dec | 100 | 52 | NaN |

(apologies idk how to make a dataframe in this text editor)
I created a pivot table with indexes = ['year','month'] and I want to forward fill just score3, but only within the index. How can I get my dataframe to look like:

| Year | Month | score1 | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Jan | 98 | NaN | 100 |
|  | feb | NaN | 39 | 100 |
| 2021 | sept | 100 | 50 | NaN |
|  | nov | 100 | NaN | 76 |
|  | dec | 100 | 52 | 76 |

Comment: The pandas tag wiki contains a link to a canonical question about how to create reproducible dataframes

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
df['score3'] = df['score3'].groupby(level='Year').ffill()
```

Or, for a more generic way:

```
cols = ['score3']
df[cols] = df.groupby(level='Year')[cols].ffill()
```

Comment: hmm this isn't working. it still fills into the next year

Comment: @lost please provide a reproducible example for which it doesn't work.